# Processing of the LINQ expression ... failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework

"Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet<Log_Service_ExportToFile>.ElementAt(__p_0)' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core."

I am getting this error in my application employing Entity Framework Core 3.0. From my code:

```
private void UpdateLogService(DateTime t)
        {
            var Log_Service_ExportToFile_List = dbContext.Log_Service_ExportToFile.ToList();
            bool found = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < Log_Service_ExportToFile_List.Count(); i++)
            {
                var s = Log_Service_ExportToFile_List[i];
                if (s.MandantId == Config.MandantId && s.ForWhichTime == t)
                {
                    dbContext.Log_Service_ExportToFile.ElementAt(i).UTC = DateTime.Now;
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found) return;
            var logservice = new Log_Service_ExportToFile
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                UTC = DateTime.Now,
                FileName = Config.Path,
                MandantId = Config.MandantId,
                ForWhichTime = t
            };
            dbContext.Log_Service_ExportToFile.Add(logservice);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The line where the Compiler cries is:

```
dbContext.Log_Service_ExportToFile.ElementAt(i).UTC = DateTime.Now;
```

The class Log_Service_ExportToFile is defined as follows:

```
public class Log_Service_ExportToFile
{
    public Log_Service_ExportToFile()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime UTC { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string MandantId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ForWhichTime { get; set; }
}
```

Inside the class that inherits from DbContext I have defined:

```
public virtual DbSet<Log_Service_ExportToFile> Log_Service_ExportToFile { get; set; }
```

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Log_Service_ExportToFile>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("LOG_SERVICE_EXPORTTOFILE");
    entity.Property(e => e.UTC).HasColumnType("datetime");
    entity.Property(e => e.FileName).HasColumnType("ntext");
    entity.Property(e => e.MandantId).HasColumnType("ntext");
    entity.Property(e => e.ForWhichTime).HasColumnType("datetime");
});
```

Comment: use `Log_Service_ExportToFile_List` instead of `dbContext.Log_Service_ExportToFile` when using the `ElementAt(i)` method.

Comment: You should set `s.UTC`.

Comment: Both suggestions would, to my knowledge, not get the updated information to be written to the database.

Comment: To your knowledge. That may be a feeble basis. Did you try?

Comment: OK, I've tried it and the database was updated, contrary to what I had believed. So, thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Converting the `dbContext.Log_Service_ExportToFile` to a `List` before using the `ElementAt` should fix the problem.

Try converting

```
dbContext.Log_Service_ExportToFile.ElementAt(i).UTC = DateTime.Now;
```

to

```
dbContext.Log_Service_ExportToFile.ToList().ElementAt(i).UTC = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).